# How to run my own instance of freegeoip on my own server

Tags: webserver, freegeoip

I'm evelauting using thie service. http://www.freegeoip.net/ & i quote the text below.

> The freegeoip web server is free and open source so if the public service limit is a problem for you, download it and run your own instance

The public service limit of 10,000 queries per hour by default might or might not be a problem for me, so i just want to take the safe route early enough by downloading it and running my own instance.

However, i have zero experience on deploying such a server. Does any one here have or know of a walk-through that can get me started deploying my won instance. Can i host this server on windows or my own instance must be hosted on a linux server?

*My site is hosted in IIS on windows.*

Comment: Now, after the freegeoip is an official company with pricing model, the freegeoip is deprecated. Thus, everyone who has been using the https://freegeoip.net/json url, faced an 404 response with a big message about signing up to the new API. Consequently, this question might become very popular. It would be perfect if anyone solve this issue by posting it's implementation on how to deploy the project on self-hosted IIS.